# segmentation fault (core dumped)-iteration function

Tags: c++

I'm setting up a iteration function which calls another function to make some calculus and then find the value when it finally converges. But it gets stuck in an error saying it is a segmentation fault (core dumped).

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath> 
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

double calcular(int numero)
{
    return 1.0555 - (0.24366 * (numero - 0.0555) / (numero * (numero + 0.0555)));
}

double iterar(int hola)
{
    if (abs(calcular(hola) - hola) > 0.002)
    {
        hola = calcular(hola);
        iterar(hola);
    }
    else
        return hola;
}

int main()
{
    cout << iterar(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are calling `iterar` repeatedly and you are getting a stack buffer overflow.

Comment: `iterar(hola);` -> `return  iterar(hola);`

Comment: The result of `calcular(1)` is approximately `0.837`. When you assign that value to `hola` it will become *zero* (as you truncate the floating point value to an integer value). Think about what happens when you call `calcular(0)`. And a hint for figuring it out yourself: [Learn how to debug your programs!](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

```
double calcular(int numero)
{
    return 1.0555 - (0.24366 * (numero - 0.0555) / (numero * (numero + 0.0555)));
}
double iterar(int hola)
{
    if (abs(calcular(hola) - hola) > 0.002)
    {
        hola = calcular(hola);
        iterar(hola);
    }
    else
        return hola;
}
```

should be

```
double calcular(double numero)
{
    return 1.0555 - (0.24366 * (numero - 0.0555) / (numero * (numero + 0.0555)));
}
double iterar(double hola)
{
    if (abs(calcular(hola) - hola) > 0.002)
    {
        hola = calcular(hola);
        return iterar(hola);
    }
    else
        return hola;
}
```

as you are passing fraction values to calcular. Segmentation fault when numero < 1, it will take 0, and (numero * (numero + 0.0555)) will become 0.

Comment: Yes it should be  return iterar(hola);, but surprisingly my compiler giving correct answer even without return!

Comment: Undefined behaviour is like that - you can't tell that it's not there by looking for it.